# Как правильно реализовать ассоциацию?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте!

Есть модель **Product** у которой есть только один параметр, например **age** который берется из записи соответствующей модели **Age**, но этот параметр может также принадлежать и другой модели.

Записи модели **Age** из которых берется параметр для модели **Product** выглядят так:

```
Age.all
id: 1, name: "Взрослый"
id: 2, name: "Юниор"
id: 3, name: "Детский"
```

Сейчас все работает через связь belongs_to:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :age
  ...
end
```

Схема таблицы **Products**

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "age_id"
    ....
end
```

Так вообще правильно делать? Меня смущает, что сейчас **Product** принадлежит к параметру, хотя наверное должно быть наоборот.

Например так:

```
class Product
  has_one :age
  ...
end
```

и что-то на обратной стороне связи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет-нет, так и должно быть.

Не придавайте `belongs_to` больше значения, чем в нём есть: эта ассоциация означает, что в этой модели есть **внешний ключ** (`<что-то>_id`), ссылка на какую-то строчку в БД.

На секунду представьте, что ссылка бы размещалась с обратной стороны, потому что ассоциации `has_` это и предполагают. Представили? Безумненько? Хе-хе.

Такую колонку можно сделать в любой таблице. *Можно даже несколько в одной* (если это имеет смысл; тогда придётся указывать внешние ключи самому как минимум в одном случае, и назвать ассоциации придётся по-разному).

Как тогда получить все объекты, "принадлежащие" модели? Ну... Сначала убедитесь, что вам это вообще потребуется. Неоднородные списки нужны **крайне редко**. Как правило, вы хотите модели только одного вида, или, максимум, *наследников* (STI) одной модели — важно, что из одной таблицы. Поскольку реляционные БД представляют данные в виде таблиц, паковать объекты разных видов в одно множество значит получать в каждой строчке килограмм `NULL`ов, что нерационально.

Просто сделайте отдельные `has_many` на каждую такую связь, если вам вообще нужна связь в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Возраст:

```
class Age < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Продукт:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Таблица с продуктами содержит внешний ключ
  belongs_to :age
end
```

Как работает:

```
Age.first.products # Продукты с одним возрастом
Product.first.age.name # Имя возраста, указанного у продукта
```

Comment: Так и реализовано, просто семантика отношений в таком случае подразумевает, что не параметр принадлежит продукту, а наоборот, что как бы немного противоречиво.

Вопрос в том как именно проектируются такие связи, может есть более правильный вариант без использования внешних ключей в таблице продуктов например.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все верно, если нужно получить age на конктреном продукте:
@product = Product.first
@product.age - получишь возраст конкретного объекта продукт.